# scripts to manage service start under windows

Tags: windows, service, process, task

I'm currently looking for the best way to manage a service start/stop under windows.

I will use the task sheduler provided by windows to start a script at a specific time.

The goal of the script is to :

- check if the process "X" is running
- if not service Y can be started
- if yes, check in one hour if the process "X" is still running

And also what is the best language to do it ? Is Python a good choice ?

Sebastien

Comment: I would recommend [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394582(v=vs.85).aspx) for managing services under Windows. But this might be overkill for what you want...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a batch script (save as .bat)

```
tasklist /nh /fi "imagename eq x.exe" | find /i "x.exe" >nul && goto :HOURCHECK || net start Y
exit >nul    
:HOURCHECK
timeout /t 3600
tasklist /nh /fi "imagename eq x.exe" | find /i "x.exe" >nul && REM Running || REM Not Running
```

Just replace my `REM` comments to do what you want when it checks after an hour.